Understanding the Purpose of detach Method in PyTorch
I wanted to understand the purpose of the detach method in PyTorch. Below is an example. If you look into the update_delta method, you see the detach method being used. I don't understand what the author is trying to achieve by using detach.
class PerturbationLayer(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, learning_rate=1e-4, init_perturbation=1e-2):
        super().__init__()
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.init_perturbation = init_perturbation
        self.delta = None
        self.LayerNorm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(hidden_size, 1e-7, elementwise_affine=False)
        self.adversarial_mode = False

    def adversarial_(self, adversarial=True):
        self.adversarial_mode = adversarial
        if not adversarial:
            self.delta = None

    def forward(self, input):
        if not self.adversarial_mode:
            self.input = self.LayerNorm(input)
            return self.input
        else:
            if self.delta is None:
                self.update_delta(requires_grad=True)
            return self.perturbated_input

    def update_delta(self, requires_grad=False):
        if not self.adversarial_mode:
            return True
        if self.delta is None:
            delta = torch.clamp(
                self.input.new(self.input.size())
                .normal_(0, self.init_perturbation)
                .float(),
                -2 * self.init_perturbation, 2 * self.init_perturbation,
            )
        else:
            grad = self.delta.grad
            self.delta.grad = None
            delta = self.delta
            norm = grad.norm()
            if torch.isnan(norm) or torch.isinf(norm):
                return False
            eps = self.learning_rate
            with torch.no_grad():
                delta = delta + eps * grad / (
                    1e-6 + grad.abs().max(-1, keepdim=True)[0]
                )
        self.delta = delta.float().detach().requires_grad_(requires_grad)
        self.perturbated_input = (self.input.to(delta).detach() + self.delta).to(
            self.input
        )
        return True


Questions:
What does the detach method do in this context?
Why is it necessary to use detach when updating delta?

Any insights would be appreciated!

As far as I understand, the .detach() method is used to remove the current tensor from the directed acyclic graph (DAG) used for computing gradients of each operation you do. This is a part of autograd and you can find a PyTorch tutorial here.
I'm not one hundred percent sure of the use case you have here but it seems to me that the author is trying to do some adversarial attack by manipulating the input to a network. It might just be a way of the author trying to explain that you don't need any gradients for the perturbed input image and for the delta you used to perturb it. This discussion on the PyTorch forum might help.
In my work, I had to always use detach when converting PyTorch tensors to numpy arrays but I don't think it is the case here.
The best way to see how important it is in your example would be to just remove the .detach() calls and run the whole program and see what happens. My hunch is that it won't change much but it depends on where and how this layer is used.
Hope this helps.
